# Migrating WorkItems that have no longer existing 'Team Project' references in their history fails

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

While migrating a project across two distinct Azure DevOps Organizations with the following config for the processor:

```
{
  "ObjectType": "VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.Configuration.Processing.WorkItemMigrationConfig",
  "Enabled": true,
  "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
  "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
  "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
  "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
  "LinkMigration": true,
  "AttachmentMigration": true,
  "AttachmentMazSize": 480000000,
  "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",      
  "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": true,
  "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": false,
  "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
  "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
  "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": false,
  "BuildFieldTable": false,
  "QueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan') ",
  "OrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
  "ReplayRevisions": true,
  "CollapseRevisions": false
}
```

The process fails in the items that, in any of their revisions, reference Team Projects that no longer exist - those items were moved across projects within the same Organization in the past, and the originating project was in the meanwhile deleted.

```
[          User Story][Complete:  18/3284][sid:1471  |Rev:64 ][tid:null   | Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DeniedOrNotExistException: TF26192: The team project specified by the ID 129 does not exist. Check the team project ID and try again.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ProjectCollection.GetById(Int32 projectId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.CheckUpdateCachedData(Boolean projectChanged, Boolean typeChanged)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.get_Type()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemFieldData.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Internals.IWorkItemOpenFieldDataHelper.SetLatestData(Dictionary`2 latestData)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Internals.WorkItemHelper.LoadWorkItemFieldData(IRowSetCollectionHelper tables, IWorkItemOpenFieldDataHelper helper)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem.LoadWorkItemFromRowSetInternal(Int32 rev, Nullable`1 asof, IWorkItemRowSets witem)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItem..ctor(WorkItemStore store, Int32 id, Int32 revision)
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemStoreContext.GetRevision(WorkItem workItem, Int32 revision) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\ComponentContext\WorkItemStoreContext.cs:line 202
   at VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext.ReplayRevisions(List`1 revisionsToMigrate, WorkItem sourceWorkItem, WorkItem targetWorkItem, Project destProject, WorkItemStoreContext sourceStore, Int32 current, WorkItemStoreContext targetStore) in D:\a\1\s\src\VstsSyncMigrator.Core\Execution\MigrationContext\WorkItemMigrationContext.cs:line 361
```

Is there any way to overcome this while maintaining the full revision history?
The issue is overcome if I migrate only the tip revisions.

Comment: I mitigated the issue by changing the code to iterate only on the loadable revisions.

Comment: You might want to put this as an answer to your own question

Comment: @JoãoMacedoPinto I would recommend that you submit a PR with those changes. That would help out others.